# Elasticsearch - Do searches for alternative country codes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with a field called 'countryCode'. I have a term query that search for the keyword value of it. But having some issues with:

- Some records saying UK and some other saying GB
- Some records saying US and some other USA
- And the list goes on..

Can I instruct my index to handle all those variations somehow, instead of me having to expand the terms on my query filter?

Comment: You can use a logstash plugin to update GB to UK and USA to US when adding data to elasticsearch. eg:  `filter {mutate {gsub => ["country", "USA", "US","country", "GB", "UK",]} }`

Comment: hmm, great suggestion. However this is actually some data being pushed via API by several 3rd party apps, no logstash involved. And I could tell everyone to clean their data or put like a sanitiser endpoint in front of my elasticsearch server, but I'm checking if ES can do it for me instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to have your tokens understand similar tokens which may or may not be having similar characters. This is only possible using `synonyms`.

`Elasticsearch` provides you to configure your `synonyms` and have your query use those `synonyms` and return the results accordingly.

I have configured a field using a `custom analyzer` using `synonym token filter`. I have created a sample mapping and query so that you can play with it and see if that fits your needs.

### Mapping

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_synonym_filter": {
          "type": "synonym",
          "synonyms": [
            "usa, us",
            "uk, gb"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_synonyms": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_synonym_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mydocs": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "my_synonyms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document

```
POST my_index/mydocs/1
{
  "name": "uk is pretty cool country"
}
```

And when you make use of the below query, it does return the above document as well.

### Query

```
GET my_index/mydocs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "gb"
    }
  }
}
```

Refer to their official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) to understand more on this. Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you, this is the solution I ended up following and no complaints so far

Answer (score 0):

Handling within ES itself without using logstash, I'd suggest using a simple ingest pipeline with gsub processor to update the field in it's place

```
{
  "gsub": {
  "field": "countryCode",
  "pattern": "GB",
  "replacement": "UK"
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/gsub-processor.html